# Flutter's TextPainter throws an '!_needsLayout': is not true.' exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

I try to use a `TextPainter` to get the maximum length of a string in a Text Widget, but if I call the painter, it will throw an `!_needsLayout': is not true.` exception.

**Exception**

```
The following assertion was thrown building FeedPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _FeedPageState#9c489):
'package:flutter/src/painting/text_painter.dart': Failed assertion: line 546 pos 12: '!_needsLayout': is not true.
```

**Method with TextPainter**

```
int maxCharCountToFit(String content) {
    List<String> splitted = content.split(" ");

    for (int i = splitted.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      bool retry = TextPainter(
            text: TextSpan(text: splitted.sublist(0, splitted.length - i).join(" "), style: pageTextStyle),
            maxLines: 25,
            textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          ).didExceedMaxLines ==
          false;

      if (retry == false) {
        return splitted.sublist(0, i).length;
      }
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

**Complete file**

Please [see this file on GitHub](https://github.com/tscholze/flutter-surfaceduo-rssbook/blob/main/lib/ui/region/feed/feed_page.dart).

Comment: Im also getting this exception when I dismiss a keyboard and select something new very quickly, I guess its loading something that queries the phone dimensions but I don't have anything like that in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of the painted text is not calculated until you call `layout`. This must be done before accessing any size-related properties like `didExceedMaxLines`.

Consult the [API documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter/layout.html) for more information.